# Pull used Cocoapods into TableView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want to add acknowledgement page in my app. I was gonna make it a TableView so it is scalable.

Instead of manually creating the list of Pods used in my app. I was wondering if there was any way to pull that into an array or dictionary so I can use it in a tableview.

Comment: Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you don't need to manually list your Cocoapods. You can automatically put them in settings, along with their licenses. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/Acknowledgements)

Comment: @AndyIbanez's suggestion is a good one. As that link says, "There is a markdown file, for general consumption, as well as a property list file that can be added to a settings bundle for an iOS application." In your code, load that markdown file as a resource and put its contents in a label or non-editable text view.